# ngClass not updating class dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the appearance of my navbar whenever the scroll is not at the top.

I'm using Angular Material `CdkScrollable` and I'm successfully retrieving the scroll Event which gives me the data about how far it is to the top.

The issue I have is that the CSS classes never changes when I scroll. I'm verifying with a `console.log` that the variable `isScrolled` is updated properly whenever I scroll down and up to the top again. So that seems to work OK. I'm using a `ngClass` with a ternary to validate which CSS class that should apply.

Something obvious that I'm missing?

html

```
<nav [ngClass]="isScrolled ? 'navbar-desktop-scrolled' : 'navbar-desktop'">
   ...
</nav>
```

ts

```
export class MainNavComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer, { static: false }) sidenavContainer: MatSidenavContainer;

 isScrolled: boolean = false;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sidenavContainer.scrollable.elementScrolled().subscribe((x) => {
      if ((<Element>x.target).scrollTop > 0) {
        this.isScrolled = true;
      } else {
        this.isScrolled = false;
      }

      console.log(this.isScrolled);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz. There are too many unknowns in what you posted.

Comment: You do not scroll on the `MatSidenavContainer` but on the `host` element, so no scroll event is fired. Also there is no `target` property on `x`. The result is simply `{isTrusted: true}`.

Comment: You can only look if the user has scrolled, and not the scroll position. For this you can use [Angular CDK scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api).

Comment: I have created a more clear example now, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qp6jmh. As you can see the MatSidenavContainer is indeed reacting to scroll events. I'm logging the scrollTop value to the console. Do you mean it's mandatory to use the async pipe here in order for the DOM to detect changes? Feel free to edit the StackBlitz. My goal is to have the navbar background-color to change from darkblue to lightblue as you see per the CSS-classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything works fine after I added change detection functionality.

```js
export class MainNavComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer, { static: false }) sidenavContainer: MatSidenavContainer;

 isScrolled: boolean = false;

 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sidenavContainer.scrollable.elementScrolled().subscribe((x) => {
      if ((<Element>x.target).scrollTop > 0) {
        this.isScrolled = true;
      } else {
        this.isScrolled = false;
      }

      this.ref.detectChanges();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because the changes are not detected. Use an Observable in combination with the `async` pipe instead. It handles subscriptions automatically for you.

```js
export class MainNavComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer, { static: false }) 
  sidenavContainer: MatSidenavContainer;
  navbarType$: Observable<string>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.navbarType$ = this.sidenavContainer.scrollable.elementScrolled().pipe(
      map(x => x.target.scrollTop > 0
        ? 'navbar-desktop-scrolled'
        : 'navbar-desktop'
      )
    )
  }
}
```

And in your template use

```html
<nav [ngClass]="navbarType$ | async"></nav>
```

Comment: I tried with async pipe but I can't get it to work. Here's a StackBlitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bcnpr

Answer (score 0):

use `ngClass` in the object syntax like

```
<nav [ngClass]="{'navbar-desktop-scrolled' :isScrolled, 'navbar-desktop': !isScrolled}">
   ...
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation: [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description)

*Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.*

It should look like something like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'navbar-desktop-scrolled': isScrolled , 'navbar-desktop' : !isScrolled  }">...</some-element>
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to also says: *string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added*.